# Graph of people's connections in Python

Tags: python, graph, relation

There is a set of data in tabular form with information about people. What Python libraries can be used to build a graph or a tree of relationships based on them? For example, we select a person through a filter or by entering textbox, etc., we get a graph of connections, where the main vertex is the selected person, then the second vertex is the parameter for which there is a connection, the third level of vertices is the person with whom there is a connection. There is no code yet, tell me where to start, maybe there are some templates in python?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfQpg.jpg)

Comment: See this excellent [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-networks-in-python-d70f4cbeb259) which discusses using `networkx` to create a graph of relationships and then `PyViz` to visualize it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `networkx` library to build your graphs. The persons will act as `nodes` and the connection parameters will act as `edges`. If you need any graph based algorithms to be implemented in your people network, it is available out-of-box in `networkx`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `knowledge graphs` from the `NLP: Natural Language Processing`.

The python module that you could start with  is `Spacy`

For more information, you could look up here: [link](https://programmerbackpack.com/python-nlp-tutorial-information-extraction-and-knowledge-graphs/)

Comment: accept this as an answer, if you find it useful.